# BizTalk: Can't deploy two schema assemblies that both reference that same base assembly

Tags: reference, schema, biztalk, biztalk-deployment

I'm having trouble deploying some schemas:

I have assemblyA containing schemaA, assemblyB containing schemaB which references assemblyA and assemblyC containing schemaC and also referenceing assemblyA.

I can deploy asssemblyA fine and see schemaA in schemas in BizTalk Admin.

I can deploy EITHER assemblyB or assemblyC fine and see the corresponding schema in BizTalk admin.

If I try to deploy assemblyC when assemblyB is already deployed, then then assemblyB disappears from BizTalk admin along with its schema (and vice versa).

If I remove the reference to assemblyA from either B or C then I can deploy all three together just fine (but that reference is required in real case).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To fix:

From Visual Studio Solution Explorer, select all the projects you want to deploy, right click and select 'Deploy Selection'.

Comment: And you have to select all of them (A,B,&C) each time